# Why is this not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr, c++14

In this trivial example, `test2` fails to compile even though `test1` succeeds, and I don't see why that is the case. If `arr[i]` is suitable for a return value from a function marked `constexpr` then why can it not be used as a non-type template argument?

```c++
template<char c>
struct t
{ 
    static const char value = c;
};

template <unsigned N>
constexpr char test1(const char (&arr)[N], unsigned i)
{
    return arr[i];
}

template <unsigned N>
constexpr char test2(const char (&arr)[N], unsigned i)
{
    return t<arr[i]>::value;
}

int main()
{
    char a = test1("Test", 0); //Compiles OK
    char b = test2("Test", 0); //error: non-type template argument 
                               //is not a constant expression
}
```

Edit: This makes no difference:

```c++
template<char c>
struct t
{ 
    static const char value = c;
};

template <unsigned N>
constexpr char test1(const char (&arr)[N])
{
    return arr[0];
}

template <unsigned N>
constexpr char test2(const char (&arr)[N])
{
    return t<arr[0]>::value;
}

int main()
{
    char a = test1("Test"); //Compiles OK
    char b = test2("Test"); //error: non-type template argument 
                            //is not a constant expression
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Short answer: there are no `constexpr` function parameters in `C++11/14`.

Longer answer: in `test1()`, if `i` is not a compile-time constant, the function is still usable at run-time. But in `test2()`, it cannot be known to the compiler whether `i` is a compile-time constant, and yet it is required for the function to compile.

E.g. the following code for `test1` will compile

```
int i = 0;    
char a = test1("Test", i); // OK, runtime invocation of test1()

constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr char a = test1("Test", i); // also OK, compile time invocation of test1()
```

Let's simply your `test2()` to

```
constexpr char test3(unsigned i)
{
    return t<i>::value;
}
```

This will not compile for `test3(0)` because inside `test3()`, it cannot be proven that `i` is an **unconditional** compile-time expression. You would need `constexpr` function parameters to be able to express that.

### Quote from the Standard

**5.19 Constant expressions [expr.const]**

> 2 A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> — an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of
>   reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and
>   either
>    — it is initialized with a constant expression or
>
> — it is a non-static data member of an object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

This section has the following code example corresponding to your question:

```
constexpr int f1(int k) {
    constexpr int x = k; // error: x is not initialized by a
                         // constant expression because lifetime of k
                         // began outside the initializer of x
    return x;
}
```

Because `x` in the above example is not a constant expression, it means that you can't instantiate templates with either `x` or `k` inside `f1`.

Comment: That is not the case. If you remove `unsigned i` from `test2` and instead index as `arr[0]` you still get the same compile error.

Comment: See for example what your compiler says if you try `t<test1(arr,i)>::value` in test2. Clearly test1 isn't a constexpr in this case, because `arr` and `i` are runtime arguments _in the general case_. The function has to compile whether they're literals or not.

Comment: Are "constexpr function parameters" something which could possibly be added to the language?

Comment: Not unless someone writes a proposal. I think it has been suggested on the std-proposals newsgroup. But `constexpr` lambdas e.g. is something that would be higher on my wish list.

Answer (score 8):

There's a misconception of what `constexpr` does here. It indicates that a function must be evaluatable at compile time for suitable arguments, but it does *not* remove the requirement still to compile in the general case.

Let's take the first version:

```
template <unsigned N>
constexpr char test1(const char (&arr)[N], unsigned i) {
    return arr[i];
}
```

Now, this is clearly a compile-time evaluation:

```
enum { CompileTimeConstant = test1("Test", 0) };
```

your example *may* be, but it's an optimizer/QoI issue:

```
char MayBeCompileTimeConstant = test1("Test", 0);
```

and this example obviously isn't, but is *still required to be evaluatable*

```
char arr[10];
int i;
std::cin >> i;
std::cin >> arr;
char b = test1(arr, i);
std::cout << "'" << arr << "'[" << i << "] = " << b << '\n';
```

Since `test2` can't possibly compile in for the last case, it can't compile at all. (Please note I'm not suggesting that code is *good*).

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that calling `arr[i]` evokes the subscript operator `operator[]`. **This operator doesn't return a constant expression.**

It's not a problem of `constexpr` actually, is a problem of template argument deduction. A Non type template argument must be a constant expression which the return argument of subscript operator is not.

Therefore, the compiler rightfully complains that `arr[i]` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

Because `arr[i]` is not compile-time constant expression. It can be different at run-time.

Comment: That is not the case. If you remove unsigned i from test2 and instead index as arr[0] you still get the same compile error.

Comment: @Chris_F `arr[i]` (even `arr[0]`) is not compile-time constant, even if it is `const char[]`.

Comment: @Chris_F `error: an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression`

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it with dynamic array sizing. you can use vector class for this, because in vector class you can resize your list dynamically. or you can use malloc but it would be such a waste of time while the vector class is standing there. alls im sayin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).